# Build Docker with Go app: cannot find package

Tags: docker, go

I have my Dockerfile in the root of directory with `src/myapp` folder, `myapp` contains `myapp.go` with main package.

`Dockerfile` looks like following:

```
FROM golang:1.9.2

ADD . /
RUN go build myapp;

ENTRYPOINT ["/go/bin/myapp"]
```

I get following error:

```
can't load package: package myapp: cannot find package "myapp" in any of:
    /usr/local/go/src/myapp (from $GOROOT)
    /go/src/myapp (from $GOPATH)
```

What am I doing wrong? Can I log `ls` command after docker has done `ADD`?

Comment: The answers are correct in that you need to ensure that your app is properly copied into the go path.  However, this assumes that you have vendored all dependencies - if not, you may may need `go get` or dep to make sure these are available.  If the objective however, is to make your binary portable, then compiling for linux outside of docker, copying the binary and then building a lightweight container from scratch may be a better approach as you will not inadvertently ship all of your source code in the app.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You are copying all the files to Image root directory, Didn't installed any dependencies, Trying to Build it and then run the binary from `/go/bin/app`. The binary doesn't exists in that directory and it's generating errors.

I would recommend using a Dockerfile like this,

```
FROM golang:1.9.2 
ADD . /go/src/myapp
WORKDIR /go/src/myapp
RUN go get myapp
RUN go install
ENTRYPOINT ["/go/bin/myapp"]
```

This'll do the following.

1. Copy project files to `/go/src/myapp`.
2. Set Working directory to `/go/src/myapp`.
3. Install dependencies, I used go get but replace it with which ever dependency management tool you are using.
4. Install/build the binary.
5. Set entry point.

You can run `ls` or any other command using `docker exec`.

Example:

```
docker exec <image name/hash> ls
```

You can also enter the shell in the generated image to understand it well using

```
docker run --rm -it <image hash/name> /bin/sh
```

Answer (score 9):

After experiments I've come to this way of building Golang apps.

This way has several advantages:

- dependencies are installed on build stage
- if you need you may uncomment test options
- build first fully-functional image about 800 MB
- copies your program to an fresh empty image and produces very small image about 10 MB

**`Dockerfile`**:

```
# Two-stage build:
#    first  FROM prepares a binary file in full environment ~780MB
#    second FROM takes only binary file ~10MB

FROM golang:1.9 AS builder

RUN go version

COPY . "/go/src/github.com/your-login/your-project"
WORKDIR "/go/src/github.com/your-login/your-project"

#RUN go get -v -t  .
RUN set -x && \
    #go get github.com/2tvenom/go-test-teamcity && \  
    go get github.com/golang/dep/cmd/dep && \
    dep ensure -v

RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 go build  -o /your-app

CMD ["/your-app"]

EXPOSE 8000



#########
# second stage to obtain a very small image
FROM scratch

COPY --from=builder /your-app .

EXPOSE 8000

CMD ["/your-app"]
```

Comment: This approach is nice. I never really understood multistage Docker images before. Thanks.

Comment: I think you don't need CMD, EXPOSE in first FROM

Comment: Aka The Builder pattern https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wGz_cbtCiEA&t=8s

Answer (score 5):

For go 1.11 , you can use go module, the following is example

```
FROM alpine AS base
RUN apk add --no-cache curl wget

FROM golang:1.11 AS go-builder
WORKDIR /go/app
COPY . /go/app
RUN GO111MODULE=on  CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 go build -o /go/app/main /go/app/cmd/myapp/main.go

FROM base
COPY --from=go-builder /go/app/main /main
CMD ["/main"]
```

Answer (score 5):

The official docs suggests the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM golang:1.8

WORKDIR /go/src/app
COPY . .

RUN go get -d -v ./...
RUN go install -v ./...

CMD ["app"]
```

Please, visit https://hub.docker.com/_/golang for more info

Comment: Can you explain what `./...` refers to please?

Comment: @TheRealChx101 it refers to the path of the project

Answer (score 0):

`myapp` needs to be in `/go/src/myapp` as suggested, or in `/usr/local/go/src/myapp`. You can add it in `ADD` section.

Answer (score -2):

If the objective is to create a container that simply runs your binary, I would take different approach.

First build the binary for linux:

```
GOOS=linux CGO_ENABLED=0 go build -a -installsuffix cgo
```

Then build a lightweight docker image from scratch:

```
FROM scratch
COPY myApp 
CMD ["/myApp"]
```

Comment: There's such thing as multi-stage builds in Docker, even atm when you've wrote this post